# Display all images from folder with Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

How do I display all images from a folder with a Repeater? This is how my repeater looks now, displaying one image several times.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="FileRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/oneimage.jpg" runat="server"/>
 </li></ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

In my code behind Page_Load I call GetImageNames to get a list of all images in the folder.

```
var images = Gallery.GetImageNames();        
    FileRepeater.DataSource = images;        
    FileRepeater.DataBind();
```

I'm new at this and confused, please help!

I still can't get it to work, this is how my method `GetImageNames()` looks. I was hoping that I could use images with the repeater in some way...

```
public static List<string> GetImageNames()
{
    string imgPath = PhysicalApplicationPath +"/Images/";
    List<string> images = new List<string>();
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(imgPath);


    FileInfo[] fileInfo = directoryInfo.GetFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < fileInfo.Length; i++)
    {
        images.Add(fileInfo[i].Name);
    }
    return images;
```

Comment: Where is server tag and field name in your repeater?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<ItemTemplate>            
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# Container.DataItem %>" />         
</ItemTemplate>
```

```
string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("images"));
            var aList = from fileName in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("images")) select string.Format("/images/{0}", Path.GetFileName(fileName)); 
            Repeater1.DataSource = aList;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
```